nfc reader is not reading in flutter ios
I am using nfc_manager to read the nfc passport (e-passport). In android device app is reading nfc tag and giving the output but in ios device ready to scan window appear but don't scan the nfc. I am using iphone 12 pro for testing it. I also tried with the flutter_nfc_kit and got the same issue.
I cloned the https://github.com/okadan/flutter-nfc-manager and checked it and got the same issue.
My ios version is 17.7
I installed 4 apps from appstore:

NFC Tap
NFC.cool Tools Tag Reader
NFC Tools
NFC Checker

Only in the 4th app (NFC Checker) my mobile is reading the tag and in 1st, 2nd and 3rd I am getting the same issue.
My Question is why I am getting this issue?
Is there any something I have to enable to read nfc tag?
Here is my info.plist file:
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">

<dict>
    <key>CFBundleDevelopmentRegion</key>
    <string>$(DEVELOPMENT_LANGUAGE)</string>
    <key>com.apple.developer.nfc.readersession.formats</key>
    <array>
        <string>NDEF</string>
        <string>TAG</string>
        <string>ISO7816</string>
        <string>ISO14443</string>
        <string>FeliCa</string>
        <string>MIFARE</string>
    </array>
    <key>com.apple.developer.nfc.readersession.felica.systemcodes</key>
    <array>
        <string>12FC</string>
        <string>8005</string>
        <string>8008</string>
        <string>0003</string>
        <string>fe00</string>
        <string>90b7</string>
        <string>927a</string>
        <string>86a7</string>
        <string>04D1</string>
        <string>80DE</string>
        <string>865E</string>
        <string>8592</string>
        <string>8B5D</string>
        <string>8FC1</string>
        <string>FE00</string>
        <string>0000</string>
    </array>
    <key>com.apple.developer.nfc.readersession.iso7816.select-identifiers</key>
    <array>
        <string>A0000002471001</string>
        <string>A00000000386980701</string>
        <string>A000000003101001</string>
        <string>A000000003101002</string>
        <string>A0000000041010</string>
        <string>A0000000042010</string>
        <string>A0000000044010</string>
        <string>44464D46412E44466172653234313031</string>
        <string>D2760000850100</string>
        <string>D2760000850101</string>
        <string>00000000000000</string>
        <string>F00102030405</string>
    </array>
    <key>CFBundleDisplayName</key>
    <string>Abdox App</string>
    <key>CFBundleExecutable</key>
    <string>$(EXECUTABLE_NAME)</string>
    <key>CFBundleIdentifier</key>
    <string>$(PRODUCT_BUNDLE_IDENTIFIER)</string>
    <key>CFBundleInfoDictionaryVersion</key>
    <string>6.0</string>
    <key>CFBundleName</key>
    <string>abdox_app</string>
    <key>CFBundlePackageType</key>
    <string>APPL</string>
    <key>CFBundleShortVersionString</key>
    <string>$(FLUTTER_BUILD_NAME)</string>
    <key>CFBundleSignature</key>
    <string>????</string>
    <key>CFBundleVersion</key>
    <string>$(FLUTTER_BUILD_NUMBER)</string>
    <key>LSRequiresIPhoneOS</key>
    <true/>
    <key>UILaunchStoryboardName</key>
    <string>LaunchScreen</string>
    <key>UIMainStoryboardFile</key>
    <string>Main</string>
    <key>UISupportedInterfaceOrientations</key>
    <array>
        <string>UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait</string>
        <string>UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft</string>
        <string>UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight</string>
    </array>
    <key>UISupportedInterfaceOrientations~ipad</key>
    <array>
        <string>UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait</string>
        <string>UIInterfaceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown</string>
        <string>UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft</string>
        <string>UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight</string>
    </array>
    <key>CADisableMinimumFrameDurationOnPhone</key>
    <true/>
    <key>UIApplicationSupportsIndirectInputEvents</key>
    <true/>
    <key>NFCReaderUsageDescription</key>
    <string>Application requires access to NFC</string>
</dict>
</plist>

Here is the code of my view:
import 'dart:developer';

import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:nfc_manager/nfc_manager.dart';

class ScanView extends StatefulWidget {
  ScanView({super.key});

  @override
  State<ScanView> createState() => _ScanViewState();
}

class _ScanViewState extends State<ScanView> {
  ValueNotifier<dynamic> result = ValueNotifier(null);

  void _tagRead() async {
    bool isAvailable = await NfcManager.instance.isAvailable();
    print("--->$isAvailable");
    NfcManager.instance.startSession(
        onError: (error) async {
          log("-->${error.message}");
          NfcManager.instance.stopSession();
        },
        onDiscovered: (NfcTag tag) async {
          try {
            result.value = tag.data;
            log("==>${result}");
            NfcManager.instance.stopSession();
          } catch (e) {
            print("${e}");
          } finally {
            NfcManager.instance.stopSession();
          }
        });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Container(
        width: double.infinity,
        child: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
          children: [
              ElevatedButton(
                onPressed: () {
                  _tagRead();
                },
                child: Text("Scan"),
              ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

I also added Near Field Communication Tag Reading
Here is Xcode ScreenShot:

Here is my developer account screenshot:

Here is the screenshot of ready to scan window:

